# SQL Insert Additional Field in Distinct Filter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, distinct

I would like to insert an additional field to be used in conjunction with an existing one when retrieving records from SQL database.

Current query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) 'Date of Download', 
       ActionBy AS 'User Full Name', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) 'Number of Downloads'
FROM [dbo].[AuditLog] 
WHERE ActionTaken = 'Clicked' 
    AND Type = 'Attachment Link' 
    AND CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
    AND CONVERT(date,'" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [DateTime]), ActionBy 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) > " + limit + " 
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) DESC";
```

I would like to insert an additional filter `Remarks` with the existing `Identifier` in the `DISTINCT` filter.

*Example*:
`COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier + Remarks) 'Number of Downloads'`

May I know how can I modify my current statement?

Thank you

---

**Sample Data:**

Other columns were minimised to maximise visibility.

[image]

Comment: Post example data and expected output. The description is ambiguous otherwise.

Comment: does that mean same `FileID` can have multiple `Title`s?

Comment: @NikhilVartak yes you are correct. One `FileID` can have multiple `Title`

Comment: Don't minimize the `Title` field in sample data screenshot.

Comment: My apologies. I have renamed the fields in my initial post for better understanding. I will edit my post to match the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select field as below, by casting FileID to NVARCHAR

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(FileID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + Title) 'Number of Downloads'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) 'Date of Download', 
       ActionBy AS 'User Full Name', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) + ' ' + COUNT(DISTINCT Remarks) 'Number of Downloads' 
FROM [dbo].[AuditLog] 
WHERE ActionTaken = 'Clicked' 
    AND Type = 'Attachment Link' 
    AND CONVERT(date, [DateTime]) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'" + scanStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
    AND CONVERT(date,'" + scanEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "') 
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [DateTime]), ActionBy 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) > " + limit + " 
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Identifier) DESC";
```